# Signing a managed assembly that references an unmanaged assembly

Tags: .net, visual-studio, code-signing

I'm trying to sign a .net assembly with Visual Studio (2010).  On the properties page for the project, I selected the Signing tab, and checked "sign the assembly" and provided a strong name key file.

The problem is that this project references another -- unmanaged project.  When I try to build the .net assembly, I get the message: "Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'otherAssemblyName' does not have a strong name.

Since the other assembly/project is unmanaged, I don't believe that it is possible to sign it, and so I don't know what to do next.

I need to sign my .net assembly because it will be used by another signed assembly.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the other assembly is "unmanaged?" It's not possible to *reference* an unmanaged assembly.

C++ can generate unmanaged or managed DLLs. If you're p/Invoking the DLL, then it's unmanaged; otherwise, it's managed and can be signed.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  It was not unmanaged.  It just has a different properties screen -- I guess because it is C++.  I used this page to figure out how to sign it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35678/How-to-sign-Cplusplus-CLI-assemblies-with-a-strong.aspx